# Running Pulseaudio and Bluetooth at Start

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a headless Debian server that I use for music. It's connected to some speakers and I've set it up so that I can play music from my phone to the server via bluetooth pairing.

However, I've found that I need to have a user logged in so that I can start the bluetooth agent and pulseaudio server. What I end up doing is logging in via ssh and running `pulseaudio -D` and then `bt-agent -d`. This allows me to pair my phone to the server and play music from my phone. The problem with this is that I have to keep the user logged in and running otherwise it stops working.

How can I automatically start these daemons on boot that will persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *systemd* you could create the two systemd units shown below, enable them with `systemctl --user enable bt-agent-d.service; systemctl --user enable pulseaudio-d.service` and finally enable [lingering](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) in order to start them at boot and not to stop them if the user logs out with `loginctl enable-linger username`.

PS The 'username' in the last command is a placeholder for an *actual* username and the last command needs root privileges to succeed.

`~/.config/systemd/user/bt-agent-d.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bt-agent-d service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bt-agent -d

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

`~/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio-d.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pulseaudio-d service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/pulseaudio -D

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work yet. I forgot to mention that `bt-agent -d` has to be run after `pulseaudio -D`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I managed to fix it partially. It works with `/bin/pulseaudio -D` and `/bin/bt-agent -d` (not sure what the difference is) but somehow lingering is not working.

Comment: I got lingering to work by enabling it with pulse.

Comment: On my Arch box '/bin' symlinks to '/usr/bin', where the executables are normally located, slightly different in case of Debian. Anyways, glad you got it going :) PS. Sorry for the delay, busy with work and sleep and such.

Comment: In case the services depend on one another (for instance one service must wait for another) it can be achieved by adding a `After=xyz.target` in the '[Unit] section of the service file, in this case 'After=pulseaudio-d.target' in the 'bt-agent-d.service' '[Unit]' section.

Comment: Yeah no worries. Thanks a lot.